# MySQL CHECK constraint based upon delimiter-split hierarchical string

Tags: mysql, mariadb, check-constraints

We have a single-column table in our MySQL (10.3.27-MariaDB) database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `action` (
  `action_name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`action_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

```
+-----------------+
| action_name     |
+-----------------+
| Foo             |
| Foo.Bar         |
| Foo.Bar.Qux     |
| Foo.Baz         |
| Foo.Baz.Abc     |
| Foo.Baz.Abc.Def |
| Qux             |
| Dog             |
+-----------------+
```

The `action_name`s are hierarchical. MySQL lacking an equivalent of Postgres' LTREE means having a lot of complex workarounds to create a hierarchial structure which makes foreign key constraints and queries very difficult, so we're using dot-separated values instead.

This is working fine: our queries automatically search for all possible parent values based upon the dot delimiter. This makes our foreign key constraints simple and easy and greatly simplifies our application logic. However, the existence of parent nodes isn't enforced by any constraint and we don't want to leave this up to our application code to enforce.

Our version of MariaDB does seem to support custom check constraints. There's ways to split values by delimiter (SUBSTRING_INDEX), and there's ways to join them back together (GROUP_CONCAT).

How can we enforce these requirements?

- To add `Foo.Bar.Baz`, there needs to already exist `Foo` and `Foo.Bar` (parents must exist)
- To remove `Foo.Bar` there must not be any children (`Foo.Bar.Baz` must not exist)
- Rows cannot be updated in such a way that would cause either of the first two conditions to fail.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: Sorry, but...that's the thing -- despite all my research, I haven't been able to come up with a working solution or even partly working. But I have been able to come up with a fairly good set of requirements, description of environment, use case and reasoning, and sample data in order to post this question, in the hopes that someone here would be able to succeed where I've failed.

Comment: Well, you might be looking in the wrong direction. Check constraints won't work here as they cannot access data of other rows. And they won't get checked when a parent is deleted. There might be workarounds via (complicated) functions. Or maybe look in the direction of (complicated) triggers. Or switch to Postgres, you seem to have a solution in mind for that and it's overall more capable.

Comment: Could something such as [this hierarchical](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) information possibly help achieve the goal?